# uninstalling IE - are any DLLs used by IE removed?

Tags: internet-explorer, dll, uninstallation

When a user uninstalls IE from Windows what (if any) DLLs are removed?  I'm curious since our program depends on some of these DLLs.  Yes, I am lazy and could try myself :-)

Would also be nice to know in general what is occurring during uninstall.

Thanks.

Comment: Wait, you can uninstall it now?

Comment: Internet Explorer has been an optional component since IE8 on Windows 7; http://blogs.msdn.com/b/e7/archive/2009/03/06/beta-to-rc-changes-turning-windows-features-on-or-off.aspx

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to answer if you list what DLLs you depend on.  In general most of the DLLs that are frequently used by IE are not removed.  If you use ieframe.dll, that might be worth looking into.  But mshtml.dll, shdocvw.dll, browseui.dll... all the usual suspects should remain.